# Yum install, format - 'packageName.archName-versionNumber' says no package

Tags: yum

When i try to do `yum install body_guard` from my local repo, it shows the following package details,

```
---> Package body_guard.x86_64 0:0.2-0313 will be updated
---> Package body_guard.x86_64 0:0.2-0315 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependencies Resolved
============================================================================================================================================
===
 Package                               Arch                           Version                            Repository                       Size
===============================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 body_guard                         x86_64                         0.2-0315                           my-sg                          18 M
```

When i try to install an older version (say 312) of the same yum package, it fails `No package body_guard.x86_64-0.2-0312 available`

I used hypen as the seperator between package name and version number (format is `packageName.archName-versionNumber`), and issued the command as,

`yum install body_guard.x86_64-0.2-0312`

On doing, `yum --showduplicates`, i can see there exists a package with version numbered - `0.2-312`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [yum man page](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/yum8.html):

```
Specifying package names
              A  package can be referred to for install,update,list,remove etc
              with any of the following:

              name
              name.arch
              name-ver
              name-ver-rel
              name-ver-rel.arch
              name-epoch:ver-rel.arch
              epoch:name-ver-rel.arch

              For example: yum remove kernel-2.4.1-10.i686
```

I think you misplaced {arch} it should be at last, the correct syntax is:

```
yum install <package_name>-<version>-<rel>.<arch>
```

Try:

```
yum install body_guard-0.2-0312.x86_64
```

Comment: it says, `Package matching body_guard-0.2-0312.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update. Nothing to do`... It is not rolling back to old versions.... `rpm -qa` can confirm, the current version is `0.2-315`

Comment: then try `yum downgrade body_guard-0.2-0312.x86_64` OR `yum reinstall body_guard-0.2-0312.x86_64`